# Winforms - Datagridview dynamically change linkbutton text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am using Winforms datagridview (n-tier architecture) to populate from a dataset. I want to have a linkbutton as the last column which should change its text based on the value of two columns. While I have managed to get the linkbutton, I cannot get the value to change. I need the value to change so that when the linkbutton is clicked, it should open up different windows. My code is as below

```
Private Sub ShowProductRequisitionsInListView(ByVal data As DataSet, ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns.Clear()
    dgvRequisitionDetails.DataSource = Nothing
    dgvRequisitionDetails.DataSource = data.Tables(0)
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(0).Width = 80
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Product Code"
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(1).Width = 180
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Product Name"
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(2).Width = 150
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Sales UOM"
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(3).Width = 60
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Qty. Reqd."
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N3"
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(4).Width = 105
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Qty. In Stock"
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N3"
    Dim lnk As DataGridViewLinkColumn = New DataGridViewLinkColumn
    dgvRequisitionDetails.Columns.Add(lnk)
    lnk.HeaderText = "Action"
    lnk.Text = "Click Here"
    lnk.Name = "lnkAction"
    lnk.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = True
End Sub
```

If the difference between the QtyReqd and QtyInStock is a negative value, the link button should read as "Not Available" and if there is enough stock it should read as "Available". Based on these two values different windows will open upon clicking the link

I tried to check the condition in the DataBindingComplete event, but its not working. What am I doing wrong here?

CL

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is to add a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) to the data table and use this as the data bound item for the link column. Something like this:

```
Dim expr As String = "IFF((([QtyInStock] - [QtyReqd]) >= 0), 'Available', 'Not Available')"
data.Tables(0).Columns.Add("Action", GetType(String), expr)
```

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, the above helps but when i use the same expression in SQL Query in VB.Net, I am getting a syntax error which says "Incorrect syntax near '>'. The same query works perfectly when I run it in SQL Server Management Studio. My query is as below:

Comment: SELECT
 dbo.OrderDetails.PCode,
 dbo.OrderDetails.PName,
 dbo.OrderDetails.SUOM,
 dbo.OrderDetails.QtyOrdered,
 ISNULL(dbo.Products.QtyStock,0) AS QtyStock,
 IIF(((QtyStock - dbo.OrderDetails.QtyOrdered) >= 0), 'Available', 'Not Available') 
FROM
 dbo.OrderDetails
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Products ON (
 dbo.OrderDetails.PCode + dbo.OrderDetails.SUCode
) = (
 dbo.Products.PCode + dbo.Products.SUCode
)

Comment: I believe the correct SQL expression is `IIF(((ISNULL(dbo.Products.QtyStock,0) - dbo.OrderDetails.QtyOrdered) > 0), 'Available', 'Not Available')`.

Comment: Just a heads up: AFAIK the expression are lost when read into a data set/table. So you'll have the modify the column client side.

Answer (score 0):

In the datagrid designer add a handler for:  OnRowDataBound="someEvent_RowDataBound"

In the code behind you will have a function:

```
    protected void someEvent_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        If(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){
           ((linkbutton)e.Row.Cells[someindex].controls(0)).Text = "somevalue";
        }
    }
```